# How to take the last Request date like a history of request

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, select, union

I want to take the last request date from a union column.
I Have this code to display the last request date:

```
;with cte 
as
(
    select
        [Date], [Badge id], Name, Reason, [Item1] item, 
        row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Item1] order by getdate()) rn
    from tbl_Request2
    where [Item1] Is Not null

    union

    select
        [Date], [Badge id], Name, Reason,[Item2] item,
        row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Item2] order by getdate()) rn
    from tbl_Request2 where [Item2] is not null union
)
Select
    T.[Badge ID], T.Name, T.Item, T.Reason, T. [Date] as [Current Request],
    ISNULL((Select top 1 [Date]
            from CTE
            where
                CTE.[Badge Id]=T.[Badge Id] and 
                CTE.[Item] = T.item and 
                CTE. [Date] < T. [Date]),T. [Date]) as [Last Requested] 
From CTE T 
order by [Badge ID]
```

it does display the last record, but not the expected. It display, for example:

> ID 001 request item1 on 12/05/2014 THEN
>
> ID 001 request again Item1 on 13/05/2014 ; it display the last requested 12/05/2014 ;  and then
>
> that ID 001 request again Item1 on 14/05/2014 ; it display the last requested 12/05/2014 ; --> and Here is the ERROR 
>   I want it to display the last request 13/05/2014

The expected table:

```
 ID   |  Items     |  Date        | Last Request Date
 001  |  Item1     |  12/05/2014  | 12/05/2014 --> lets say this is the first request of ID001
 002  |  Item2     |  25/04/2014  | 20/05/2014      
 001  |  Item1     |  13/05/2014  | 12/05/2014 --> It display the date of first requested     
 001  |  Item1     |  14/05/2014  | 13/05/2014 --> display the second request date
```

Do you have any suggestion about this error?
Sorry for posting it again. I already ask this question yesterday, but it's still have some error.

Thanks in advances....

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of embarassing. I ask a question and answer it by myself. I just realize something missing on my code. I only need to remove top 1 and add max(date) on my code. Sorry for asking something that was my mistake.

```
;with cte 
as
(
    select
        [Date], [Badge id], Name, Reason, [Item1] item, 
        row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Item1] order by getdate()) rn
    from tbl_Request2
    where [Item1] Is Not null

    union

    select
        [Date], [Badge id], Name, Reason,[Item2] item,
        row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Item2] order by getdate()) rn
    from tbl_Request2 where [Item2] is not null union
)
Select
    T.[Badge ID], T.Name, T.Item, T.Reason, T. [Date] as [Current Request],
    ISNULL((Select max[Date] as [date]
            from CTE
            where
                CTE.[Badge Id]=T.[Badge Id] and 
                CTE.[Item] = T.item and 
                CTE. [Date] < T. [Date]),T. [Date]) as [Last Requested] 
From CTE T 
order by [Badge ID]
```